# Magento Set New Cookie Value

Tags: cookie

This is driving me nuts! I'm trying to set a new cookie value:

```
protected function setCookie($cookieName = null, $cookieVal = null)
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('core/cookie');
    $cookieVal = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('source');
    var_dump('Value: ' . $cookieVal);
    $theCookie = $model->set($cookieName, $cookieVal);
    return $this;
}
```

The `var_dump` spits out: `string(17) "Value: testpeanut"`. However, the cookie is never created.

I'm obviously looking for a URL query string like so: `domain.com?source=testpeanut`. If I replace the `$cookieVal =` line with the following:

```
$cookieVal = 'hardcoded_values_work';
```

Then it works as expected and the cookie is set. What the problem is? Thanks.

### ~ Edit ~

This code is part of a model observer class. Obviously, I haven't included all of my code here for cleanliness sake. If I get all the params and dump the array, my param is present and has a value:

```
$cookieVal = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
var_dump($cookieVal);
```

Also, if I pass a non-null parameter as a second argument to the `getParam()` method, it also works:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($param, 'i_can_see_this');
```

I need to check if the param is supplied in the URL, which is why that method won't work long-term. I've been tailing all the logs - no errors or warnings at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First, security:**

This pattern is extremely dangerous:

```
$cookieVal = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('source');
$theCookie = $model->set($cookieName, $cookieVal);
```

You should never accept user input and shove to a cookie - it gives a would-be attacker the instant ability to set any cookie they want from your domain.

**Secondly, cookies:**

[Insert "How do they work" meme here]

Cookies are sent back to a user session with the `Response` object. If you try to set a cookie after the header of the response you'll likely get this warning in the system.log or the general PHP log:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by //...
```

The only place you should be setting cookies is from within a controller action and before it loads the layout. If you're attempting to set cookies from anywhere else in the application you may have unexpected results.

**Finally, your real issue:**

Okay, so enough browbeating.

`getParam` is a method returned from `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` and does a series of tests:

```
public function getParam($key, $default = null)
{
    $keyName = (null !== ($alias = $this->getAlias($key))) ? $alias : $key;

    $paramSources = $this->getParamSources();
    if (isset($this->_params[$keyName])) {
        return $this->_params[$keyName];
    } elseif (in_array('_GET', $paramSources) && (isset($_GET[$keyName]))) {
        return $_GET[$keyName];
    } elseif (in_array('_POST', $paramSources) && (isset($_POST[$keyName]))) {
        return $_POST[$keyName];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

As you can see, the `$default` return value is `null` but you can change this with the second parameter. Try testing your return value. If it's null, pass a second parameter to `getParam`.

Alternatively, use of `getParams` (plural) will return all set parameters in the current request, regardless of the set method - e.g. `GET` or `POST`. Try doing a `var_dump` of `getParams` to test if your value is set.

I would also advise against using `Mage::app()->getRequest()` if you are within the scope of a controller action - instead use `$this->getRequest()`.

**Edit:**

As @vinai [pointed out in your other question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/magento-cookie-value-not-set), `var_dump` and `echo` push content to the browser and thus preclude your ability to set cookies.

Comment: Thx Phil for your in-depth, I've updated my original question. Seems like the parameter is considered `null` but I haven't a clue why.

Comment: It's null if it doesn't exist or there is no registered alias. Try using a value other than `source`. Try `mysource` for debugging, for instance.

Comment: Thx Phil. I have rephrased this question over here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/magento-cookie-value-not-set

Answer (score 0):

Solved; using `var_dump` will trigger the headers to be sent, so trying to set a cookie after that point will obviously fail.

This is not explicitly defined in the PHP manual, but if you think about it, it makes sense! They do say `...as with anything that outputs its result directly to the browser...`