# Magento Cookie Value Not Set

Tags: cookie

I'm trying to conditionally set a cookie IF a certain query string parameter exists. My Class is an observer. The `config.xml` code:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <my_module>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>setCookie</method>
                </my_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

The observer class (`app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php`):

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public $_defaultParam = null;

    public function setCookie(Varien_Event_Observer $observer = null, $setCookie = true)
    {
        $myCookie = 'source';
        $myCookieVal = $this->getQueryString($myCookie);
        $myCookiePeriod = (int) 86400 * 30;
        $myCookieEnabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('my_module/my_group/source_cookie', Mage::app()->getStore());
        if ($setCookie) {
            if ($myCookieEnabled == 1 && $myCookieVal) {
                $doCookie = $this->setCookie($myCookie, $myCookieVal, $myCookiePeriod, false);
            } else {
                if ($this->getCookie($myCookie)) {
                    $doCookie = $this->delCookie($myCookie);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $doCookie = $this->getCookie($myCookie, true);
        }
        return $doCookie;
    }

    public function getQueryString($param = null)
    {
        $queryParam = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($param, 'notset');
        $paramValue = $queryParam ? (string) $queryParam : $this->_defaultParam;
        var_dump('ParamValue: ' . $paramValue);
        return $paramValue;
    }

    public function setCookie($cookieName = null, $cookieVal = null, $cookiePeriod = 3600, $setEncode = true)
    {
        $model = Mage::getModel('core/cookie');
        if ($setEncode) {
            $cookieVal = base64_encode($cookieVal);
        }
        $curStore = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $urlPath = parse_url($curStore);
        $cookiePath = rtrim(str_replace('index.php', '', $urlPath['path']), '/');
        var_dump('CookieVal: ' . $cookieVal);
        $theCookie = $model->set($cookieName, $cookieVal, $cookiePeriod, $cookiePath);
        return $theCookie;
    }
}
```

The query string looks like this:

```
mydomain.com?some=rubbish&then=what&we=really&want=this&source=my
```

You will notice in the method `getQueryString`, I'm `var_dump`'ing the variable `$paramValue`. It' spits out `string(14) "ParamValue: my"`.

Also, in the `setCookie` method, the `var_dump` spits out `string(13) "CookieVal: my"`.

HOWEVER, the cookie is set with the value `notset`! That means the `$param` is null, yes? But the `var_dumps` tell me otherwise. Why is the correct value not set in the cookie?

I guess I've been staring at this too long and need some eyes; could be my own stupidity! Thanks for taking a look.

### ~ Edit ~

I also tried to loop through all the query string `params` by changing the `getQueryString` method to the following:

```
public function getQueryString($param = null)
{
    $queryParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    foreach ($queryParams as $pid => $p) {
        $paramValue = ($pid == 'source') ? $p : $this->_defaultParam;
    }
    var_dump('ParamValue: ' . $paramValue);
    return $paramValue;
}
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: By chance is this a source click attribution for MyAffiliateProgram?

Comment: @philwinkle Well spotted, this is an affiliate program, but for another affiliate.

Comment: Have you looked into http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/magento-affiliate.html ?

Comment: I hope you are not expecting the cookie to be set at the same time as you are using ```var_dump()``` to output some data? The reason is that var_dump() triggers the headers to be sent, so no cookie header could be sent after that.

Comment: Vinai you beauty! That is the problem. Submit as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your previous question I pointed this out, though not as concisely as Vinai, who is such a beauty :)

Comment: @philwinkle lol, yes you kinda did. I've marked it as the answer for that one. Thank you. For future visitors: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/magento-set-new-cookie-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved; thanks to @vinai for pointing out the following:

Using `var_dump` will trigger the headers to be sent, so trying to set a cookie after that point will obviously fail.

This is not explicitly defined in the PHP manual, but if you think about it, it makes sense! They do say `...as with anything that outputs its result directly to the browser...`

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347741/magento-2-4-cookie-not-setting-via-observer-code